# How MQTT is acting as bidirectional communication

Tags: client-server, mqtt

I'm not that good with networking topics. From what I read online I understood that MQTT is bidirectional communication which is on top of TCP, but in client-server architecture always client only initiate communication, but server cannot initiate communication with client. So my big question is if a device is subscribed to an topic how MQTT broker can initiate a communication with that particular device?

Is device which is subscribed to a topic connects to MQTT broker at regular interval to see if any messages available for the topic subscribed or MQTT broker can directly initiate the communication with the device.

Answer (score 0):

The roles of the Client & Server are set out in [the spec](https://docs.oasis-open.org/mqtt/mqtt/v5.0/os/mqtt-v5.0-os.html#_Toc3901003). The client "opens the Network Connection to the Server" whereas the server "accepts Network Connections from Clients" so you are correct (the server will not initiate a connection to the client).

> if a device is subscribed to an topic how MQTT broker can initiate a communication with that particular device?

Simple answer - it can't.

If the client has an active connection, the server can use that to transmit the message. It's common for clients to maintain a connection to the server, reconnecting when the connection is lost, and sending [Keep Alive](https://docs.oasis-open.org/mqtt/mqtt/v5.0/os/mqtt-v5.0-os.html#_Toc3901045) messages. The cost of maintaining a connection is [low](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42783642/11810946) and establishing a new connection [is not free](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31379943/11810946) so in many cases this is a good option.

MQTT deals with disconnected clients through [sessions](https://docs.oasis-open.org/mqtt/mqtt/v5.0/os/mqtt-v5.0-os.html#_Session_State). Basically the server will store information about a clients subscriptions and, should any matching messages be received, add those messages to the session state. When the client reconnects the waiting messages are transmitted. Note that a range of criteria must be met for a subscription to survive the disconnection of a client (and this differs somewhat between V3 and V5 of the protocol).

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer, so that means client at regular intervals try to connect to MQTT server and when ever it connects server will transmit all the messages which are supposed to send to this client, am I right?

Comment: No, the client connects once, and keeps the connection open forever

Comment: "at regular intervals try to connect" - you can take this approach if required (e.g. if you cannot maintain comms due to power consumption). In most cases it's better to connect once and maintain that connection (i.e. if the connection drops you reconnect immediately; most libraries will handle this for you).